# Kill only processes (instances) of specific Java jar

Tags: linux, bash, grep, kill

I need to create automatic script, which kills running processes of specific Java JARs.

I do it manually like this:

```
jps -v

6753 Jps
4573 myJarToKill.jar
4574 notMyJarToKill.jar
4576 myJarToKill.jar
```

I pick up specific processes according JAR name for example myJarToKill.jar and run to kill them.

```
kill 4573 4576
```

Is it possible to get numbers of this processes by grep or sth like this? A pass it to kill command?

Comment: you can grep for the jar name and use sed to just get the number (remove the rest of the line) and then do a for loop to call kill for each number

Comment: Learn about [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to use is a combination of grep, awk, and xargs unix command:

```
jps -v | grep "<your file name>" | grep -v "<if you need to exclude other output>" |awk '{print $<field number>}'|xargs kill -<kill signal>
```

Before to execute it please read the following explanation:

first of all run this:
    jps -v  | grep "myJarToKill.jar" | awk '{print $1}'

> Note: 
>   `$2` means that the ps output is splitted in space separated field.
>   So when you run the command for the first time please check that `awk '{print $2}'` output is the expected result otherwise you should change the field number `$2` with the ones that you need.

if the "notMyJarToKill.jar" is still present add this:

```
jps -v  | grep "myJarToKill.jar" | grep -v "notMyJarToKill.jar"| awk '{print $1}'
```

Then if the output result contains the pid that you would kill you can run this

```
jps -v  | grep "myJarToKill.jar" | awk '{print $1}'|xargs kill -9
```

> Note: you could also use `kill -TERM` it's depend by your needs.

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 0):

```
kill `jps -v |grep myJarToKill|cut -f1 -d " "`
```

`cut -f1 -d " "` is the part, that extract the first "column". The commands in ` get executed and the result is given as a parameter to kill.